# How to add a custom tab in product detail page?

Tags: magento2.3, theme-overriding

[image]I want to add three more tabs below the already present details tab in product detail page as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Can anybody please help me with this?

Please see this screenshot for the location of the tab where i want it to be.

Comment: do you want separate tabs and section OR these tabs should be with other already present tabs??

Comment: I want seperate tabs in seperate section. thank you

Comment: Have you tried **easy tabs** extension?

Comment: I haven't. Can we do this without using extensions? Thank you.

Comment: https://magenticians.com/add-custom-tab-magento-2/ Try this

Comment: Tried it. But the tab comes beside the details tab. Position of my tab should be below the details tab. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have followed this to create multiple tabs, it works for me.

https://knowthemage.com/create-dynamic-custom-tabs-on-product-view-page/

Comment: Thank you. I got three tabs beside details tab. Is there any way to move these tabs below?

Comment: can you please elaborate with screenshot where you actually want to display the tabs.

Comment: I have added the screenshot which shows where i want the tabs. Please check.

Comment: I think you need to duplicate the layout of tab section.

Comment: Can i know how to duplicate the layout of tab section please? I am new to Magento.

Comment: sorry i don't know at this time, but if i find it, i will definitely share it with you

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to add new attribute and set to attribute set , then add in layout page and create .phtml in your theme.

Please follow below link.

https://blog.landofcoder.com/magento-2-product-page-layout/

Comment: The tab is coming beside the details tab. But i want it below as shown in the picture which i have added. Thank you